# Intermediate Value Theorem for Rationals

Tags: calculus

I was thinking about this.  My intuition is that there is a counterexample.  Suppose $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  Also suppose

1. If $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $f(q)\in\mathbb{Q}$.
2. $f(0)<0$
3. $f(1)>1$

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, for any rational number $r$ with $0<r<1$ there is an $x$ with $0<x<1$ such that $f(x)=r$.  Is this true of the restriction $f:\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I can't figure out why enumerate won't work.

Comment: I don't get whats in the box

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: edited.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. For an ordered field, the Intermediate Value Property is equivalent to completeness.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$ f(q) = 3 q^2 - 1 {}{}{}{}{}{}{} $$